# How to disable event sounds in Plasma 5?

Tags: audio, notifications, kde5, plasma5

I wander how to disable event sounds in kde5 Plasma (the one that is heard when scrolling the volume in systray for example).

I use Plasma in Opensuse 13.2 but this is KDE specific methinks.

---

UPDATE

These are the available settings (after answer):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In recent Plasma 5, search "Audio Volume" in the application launcher and, under 'Applications' tab, disable 'Notification Sounds'.

[image]

---

**In some Plasma versions the above doesn't work**, as I now see in Kubuntu 17.10. The Audio Volume tool looks different and notifications sounds is already muted.

[image]

To stop the volume scrolling sound etc in this case, I have unmuted,  and moved the slider to zero, and muted again. Something is buggy here though, as the slider is in fact always stuck to zero, and only the mute/unmute button does the work.

In this case I have noticed that a different tool can be used: `pavucontrol-qt`:

[image]

After using this, the bug mentioned (slider stuck to zero in "Audio Volume") disappeared.

Comment: Setting it to 0% had no effect for me. but pressing the mute button did.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor - only now I've got your point, seeing the same occurrence in Kubuntu. Edited my answer.

Comment: Just muting notification sounds didn't help me. The slider became grey, but the volume level was ca. 70% and the notification sounds were still active. I also had to set the volume level to 0%. This is somehow counter-intuitive. Must be a bug.

Comment: I used `pavucontrol-qt` to set volume > 0 since it was stuck also in main control but the the program I am using, Hexchat, is still not making any sounds.

Comment: The slider is bugged: shows that it's muted, but it's not.

Comment: Thank you. This is still bugged 7 years later. I will log it on the KDE website.

Comment: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=425974

Answer (score 4):

On KDE Plasma 5.22, Open System Settings, navigate on the menus to this place: [image: Application Settings window] and click the "Configure Events" button. This window will popup: [image: Configure Notifications window] here you can disable/change the system sounds on an individual basis.

Comment: the best answer!

Comment: But how to do it in one click? alternative for "No Sounds" theme in Windows, we have to visit each possible app and check if any event has sound notification enabled.

Answer (score 3):

in kde5, as root:

```
cd /usr/share
mv sounds sounds.backup
```

Comment: bad idea, you damage sound files itself, not force options for notifications

Answer (score 1):

It's very annoying, isn't it? I haven't found a way to disable it but muting it is easy. Fire up kmix, scroll down "Event Sounds" to the bottom. Job done.

Comment: Very odd, but I cannot find that. Kmix (version 4.6RC1) contains but 4 tabs: Playback Devices, Capture Devices, Playback Streams and Capture Streams. I see no Event Sounds anywhere.

Comment: This works for me. The Event Sounds slider is in the Playback Streams tab.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've been able to resolve this by switching to the Gstreamer audio backend instead of VLC. Once I switched backends, Kmix showed a new "PCM" slider which seems to affect notification sounds.

Comment: Well, this seems half correct now that I've had it set for a while. PCM does affect notification sounds, but that includes ALL notification sounds regardless of app; so now I can't hear my Pidgin chat alerts.